# Rails 5 CSV merge export

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to export CSV file from a table in my rails app. I can export booking.attributes.values and I can export booking.user.attributes.values separately however when I try merge these two I receive an error.

"no implicit conversion of Array into Hash"

Here is my code I am working with including some commented code. The csv file does only pull in the header for booking.attributes though. This is something extra I need to figure out.

Booking model

```
    def self.to_csv(options = {})
#       desired_columns = ["fname","lname","email","nationality","date_of_birth","phone_number"]
        CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
            csv << column_names
            all.each do |booking|
#               csv << booking.user.attributes.merge(booking.course.attributes).values_at(*desired_columns)
#               csv << booking.user.attributes.values
#               csv << booking.attributes.values
                csv << booking.attributes.merge(booking.user.attributes.values).values
            end
        end
end
```

Booking Controller

```
   def index
        @bookings = Booking.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)

        # respond to look for html but also csv data and xls
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv { send_data @bookings.to_csv }
        format.xls 
        end
    end
```

Here is the table view I am trying to recreate in CSV format. This works as intended.

```
    <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Nationality</th>
      <th scope="col">D.O.B</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Course Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Course Start</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="bookingTable">
    <% @bookings.each do | booking | %>
      <tr>
       <td scope="row"><%= booking.user.fname %> <%= booking.user.lname %></td>
        <td scope="row"><%= booking.user.email %></td>
        <td scope="row"><%= booking.user.nationality %></td>
        <td scope="row"><%= booking.user.date_of_birth&.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
        <td scope="row"><%= booking.user.phone_number %></td>
        <td scope="row"><%= booking.course.title %></td>
        <td scope="row"><%= booking.schedule.start_date&.strftime("%d %B %Y") %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'View User', user_path(booking.user), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are mismatching the booking's attributes (a hash) with the booking's user's attributes' values (an array)

Thus as the error message shows, there is no way for the computer to know which values belong to which keys.

My guess is that you intended to write:

`booking.attributes.merge(booking.user.attributes).values`

You *did* write:

`booking.attributes.merge(booking.user.attributes.values).values`

Whatever the case, the thing you are merging needs keys!

Comment: Thanks a million Dan. That did the trick alright and thanks for the explanation. mudasobwa's answer above would have led me the right way too but because you were first in and it solves my problem i've added this as the answer. Any idea on how to pull in all the columns. Right now I just get the booking headers but would like to add the booking.user headers too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSV expects an array as a row, while you are messing with hashes:

```
#      ⇓      hash      ⇓       ⇓         hash        ⇓ array ⇓ array ⇓
csv << booking.attributes.merge(booking.user.attributes.values).values
```

Merging hashes is dangerous, because if `user` have the same keys as `booking`, the latter will be discarded. What you want is probably just to add up two arrays of values:

```
csv << (booking.attributes.values + booking.user.attributes.values)
```

or, if the user’s fields are to go first:

```
csv << (booking.user.attributes.values + booking.attributes.values)
```

Comment: Thanks a million mudasobwa, Your explanation helped me understand what was going on here but Dan's got in their first and did solve the problem I had. I think you are both right. Not sure procedure on who should get the marking for it.

Comment: @Bradley once again: if both `booking` and `user` have attribute key clash (e.g. both have an attribute named “name,”) merging _hashes_ upfront would discard the former attribute. Adding arrays would save both attributes.

Comment: So by making them arrays and adding them together like so 

csv << (booking.user.attributes.values + booking.attributes.values)

Should bring in the header values even if any conflicting header names? This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sure it works. Try to produce `csv` in console with simple hashes like: `{foo: :bar}` and `{foo: 42}`.

Comment: No idea, so i've done csv_string = {foo: :bar}, {foo: 42} and got result of "{:foo=>:bar},{:foo=>42}\n" when entering: csv_string.to_csv 

I suppose this proves your point it spits out the :foo on both but I still cannot get the csv file in my app to print out anymore headers than just the booking headers and not actually booking.schedule or booking.user headers. 

Sorry it just confuses the *** out of me.